# Get user mail from o365 using graph sdk in a console app

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to read a users mail from a .net console app without user interaction.
I would like to give the app access to read only selected user(s) mail and not as global admin that can read all users mail.
I would like to use the .net Microsoft.Graph library and not raw REST interface. 
I think i need more or less step-by-step instructions i this i seven possible

I have created an new application registration and a client secret
If i give Application permission to mail it works but i cant get delegated permission to work.

The code is just one of many i have tried , but i cant really find any that do what i want to do.

```cs
var tenantId = "domain123.onmicrosoft.com";
var client_Id = "1234567789";
var client_Secret = "123243456777";
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Configure app builder
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(client_Id)
    .WithClientSecret(client_Secret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .WithLogging(MyLoggingMethod, LogLevel.Verbose,
         enablePiiLogging: true,
         enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true)
    .Build();

// Acquire tokens for Graph API
var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

// Create GraphClient and attach auth header to all request (acquired on previous step)
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

// Call Graph API
var user = await graphClient.Users["user123@domain123.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken
Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

Inner error

Comment: Try this wiki, it contains step by step instructions on how to setup everything: [Graph Managed API](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest rather than trying to roll your own DelegateAuthenticationProvider, that you use one of the provided ones? e.g.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider
Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/1.0.0-preview.1

Comment: I have changed the code to your suggestion, but i cant get it to work. The tutorial from Ivan was for Application not delegated access. I just want to allow mail download from one user.
How do i register app the right way?
I added:
var _t = await graphClient.Users["123@123site.onmicrosoft.com.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
after newGraphClient but only get ServiceException: Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken

Comment: The only way to get delegated access without user interaction is with the username password provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider

Answer (score 0):

I did try this earlier with success but since the comment on UsernamePasswordProvider is NOT RECOMMENDED I was hoping for a better solution.

To get this to work I did following steps

- Create new App registration with redirect as public client/native = myapp://auth
- Go into Authentication and set "Treat application as public client" = Yes
- To allow app to access user data, go to: 
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapp://auth&response_mode=query&scope=user.read&state=12345
- Login with user that you want to use in app , this page will hand but it ok.

Is this really the best way to do what i want?

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var GraphClient = CreateGraphClient();

            User me = await GraphClient.Me.Request()
                            .WithUsernamePassword("user123@domain123.onmicrosoft.com", new NetworkCredential("", "MyPassword").SecurePassword)
                            .GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("OK:" + me.DisplayName);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static GraphServiceClient CreateGraphClient()
        {
            string clientId = "1234567-1234-1234-12345-1234567890";
            string tenantID = "domain123.onmicrosoft.com";

            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, null);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            return graphClient;
        }
```

Another solution could be to make an application permission and then set access policy using PowerShell new-applicationaccesspolicy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps
I have not tried that one yet, anyone know if this could help?